# How to save JMeter Report with Timestamp added in ReportName

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am generating JMeter HTML report through command prompt. I want to save the report with Timestamp, so that in future i can compare these reports.  Without clearing the report folder if i am trying to execute i am getting below error message,

WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
An error occurred: Cannot write to 'D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\HtmlReports' as folder is not empty
errorlevel=1

I am using below command to execute,
jmeter -n -t D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\AgileCockpitIntegrationTest.jmx -l D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\Result\Result1.csv -e -o D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\HtmlReports\

Same with CSV file.

Please help me on this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a timestamp to .jtl results file and HTML reporting dashboard folder using Windows [date](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) and [time](https://ss64.com/nt/time.html) commands combination like:

```
jmeter -n -t D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\AgileCockpitIntegrationTest.jmx -l "D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\Result\%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.jtl" -e -o "D:\AgileCockpit_IntegrationTest\HtmlReports\%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%"
```

Different results files can be compared using [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool, the tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)